# Subtract Months from YYYYMM date in Scala

Tags: scala, date

I am trying to subtract months from YYYYMM format.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val date = 202012
val dt_format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMM")
val formattedDate = dt_format.format(date)
new DateTime(formattedDate).minusMonths(3).toDate();
```

Expected output:

202012 - 3 months = 202009,
202012 - 14 months = 201910

But it did not work as expected. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among standard date/time types [YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) seems to be the most appropriate for the given use case.

```scala
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.YearMonth

val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM")

YearMonth.parse("197001", format).minusMonths(13) // 1968-12
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about `YearMonth`. Very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the functionality in `java.time`, available since Java 8. I would have preferred coming up with a solution that did not require to adjust the input so that it could be (forcefully) parsed into a `LocalDate` (so that `plusMonths`) could be used, but at least it works.

Probably a simple regex could get the job done. ;-)

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDate

val inFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val outFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM")

def plusMonths(string: String, months: Int): String =
  LocalDate.parse(s"${string}01", inFmt).plusMonths(months).format(outFmt)

assert(plusMonths("202012", -3) == "202009")
assert(plusMonths("202012", -14) == "201910")
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/3wQgThiMS7WFQC0o3w4yDA/19).